# How to create patition by on STRING col in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have requirement to create 'partition by' on string column (YYYY-MM): example data is 2019-11.

I have tried to convert to date and then apply a partition by clause but it not workedout.
I have tried with this way:

```
create table `project.db.tgt_table`
partition by dt
as
SELECT orderid, PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", yearmonth) as dt
FROM `project.db.table`
```

can anyone please correct me where I am wrong and suggest best possible way?

Comment: Did you get any error message?

Comment: Yes I am getting an error. Failed to parse input string "2019-11"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try "%Y-%m" instead of "%Y%m%d":

```
create table `project.db.tgt_table`
partition by dt
as
SELECT orderid, PARSE_DATE("%Y-%m", yearmonth) as dt
FROM `project.db.table`
```